# Is $\sum^{\infty }_{n=1}\left[\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)}\;\right]$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is $$\sum^{\infty }_{n=1}\left[\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\ln\left(\dfrac{n+1}n\right)}\;\right]$$ convergent or divergent? *Hint:* $\ln\left( 1+x\right)<x$

This question is about series convergent & divergent. How ever, I cannot find an efficient way to solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: $\ln((n+1)/n) = \ln(1+1/n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} - \sqrt{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$
$$\sqrt{\ln\left(1+\frac 1n\right)} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$
Therefore, $$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)$$